# Power Query - Create date from datenumber and time column

Tags: excel, powerquery

In Excel's powerquery editor I have two columns. One is a daynumber (1 to 365) and the other is the time. I would like to merge the two columns to a datetime column. Day 1 will correspond with 01-01-2000. How can I do this?

For example:

- column 1: 365,
- column 2: 02:00:00
- Transform column 3: 31-12-2000 02:00:00.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this  to add a column which combines the relative date and time values:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "DateTime", each DateTime.FromText(Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(#date(1999,12,31),[#".1"])) & " " & Time.ToText([#".2"], "hh:mm:ss")), type datetime)
```

Check your logic for the date of Day 0, though - if day 1 is 01/01/2000 then day 365 <> 31/12/2000...

Answer (score 0):

Excel dates are built up on float values where the integer is the number of days passed since 1900-01-01 and the fraction is the time of day.

With that in mind 2000-01-01 is `36526`.

With the formula:

```
=36526+A1+B1
```

You get the datetime value, then just set the prefered cell format

[image]

With this formula 365 + 02:00:00 will become as you expect in question.
But 1 can't be 2000-01-01 then, it has to be 2000-01-02. Or you need to specify where to remove a day becasuse the math does not add up.

Comment: @Olly not sure I understand what you mean. OP has only requested to build a "string" date out of the values as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but indeed this does not answer the PowerQuery question.